# Emulate various screen dimensions on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, meta-tags

I just discovered that through the magic of meta tags I can emulate different screen sizes on the iPad...

For example, in landscape, this emulates screen that is 768px wide:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.333" />
```

1. Is there a way to write the desired scale in a pixel amount, rather than calculate the ratio?
2. Can the meta tag be altered after loading, via javascript to reset the scale?

Comment: Why you need it? @media css doesn't enought to control layout?

Comment: I want to use the iPad to show clients what their website would look on various screen sizes.

Comment: Will this help <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" /> ?